# In Ancient Board game what was the name of Piece called Minister

Tags: history, pieces

There are so many ancient  variants (including Dashpaad and Ashtpaad). What was the name and purpose and piece called Minister in Samskrit ot Hindi language.

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean. If the piece was called "Minister" then that was its name.

Comment: Question was specific to name only. Minister is no longer used in Modern Chess, but in asian variants minister has someother names. Minister is called deputy of monarch and was non striker but very powerful piece..

Comment: Dashpaad board is known to many chess collectors. But the game is known to handful people in india.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we go by the wikipedia as a source or reference, Minister was called Mantri in Ancient Chess game. Mantri name is no longer used in Modern or Asian Chess variants.

Western world gets confused with Minister (Mantri) as Queen(Wazeer) in Modern Chess. Arabs and Persians understood the meaning of Minister as Wazeer, but they misunderstood it with Army General. The end result - Minister became General.. Later Queen became Minister (though General)

Mantri is often called Mahamatya, Raajpurohit, Rajsachiv etc in Indian languages in ancient books.

Mantri is the deputy of Monarch and is responsible for flpw of funds, promotion of Officers, helping to break barriers.

Raajtantra was another game played on Dashpaad, with all same pieces like Shad Yantra. But in RAAJTANTRA, ther is no king and objective is to promote the Minister(Mantri) as King. Which ever promptes first wins the game.

For Dashpaad, Ashtpaad and other regional variants across Asia - please review Rick Knowlton's videos on youtube and book.